# Problem with Hibernate join query

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem with writing a join query in Hibernate although I can write it in sql. It looks like this:

```
Select * from z, y, t where z.id = y.id and t.id = z.id and z.id = 2
```

What would be the hibernate equivalent? I went through the documentation but the examples there were not very helpful in my situation or I was getting strange results. Thanks for any help.

Comment: please describe the relationship between Z, Y, and T classes

Comment: I'm pretty sure the section [14.14. HQL examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-examples) would help.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that HQL was so similar to regular SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLQuery to use the same query.User SqlQuery Class which implements Query Class.You can user createQuery method.